# OData Browser - Browse and query Stack Exchange OData

Tags: app, iphone

This app doesn't use the Stack Exchange API; instead it allows you to browse and query data via the Stack Exchange OData.

http://kruegersystems.com/Products/3/OData_Browser

## About

OData Browser enables you to query and browse any OData source. Whether you’re a developer or an uber geek who wants access to raw data, this app is for you.

## Screenshots

[Query Editor http://kruegersystems.com/Content/OData/SOEdit.png](http://kruegersystems.com/Content/OData/SOEdit.png) [Query Results http://kruegersystems.com/Content/OData/SOData.png](http://kruegersystems.com/Content/OData/SOData.png)

## Fun queries

- "Popular Users", **Users** Views ge 10000, Views desc
- "My Popular Posts", **Posts** OwnerUserId eq 338, ViewCount desc
- "My Popular Comments", **Comments** UserId eq 338, Score desc

- **Platform** iPhone
- **Price** $1.99

Comment: Please don't tag this as `app` if it doesn't use the API.

Comment: I don't know if I agree with you @geo. this is an app and http://odata.stackexchange.com/ does not have a meta site. The lines are blurred and I believe that you have to err on the side of generosity when there is no clear path.

Comment: Hmmm... you have a point there. Well, unfortunately, StackList is for API apps only - otherwise I would have suggested that.

Comment: The way I see it, StackExchange has 2 APIs: the custom one and the standard (OData) one. But I don't care to start a controversy, and will remove the tag if there are more complaints.

Comment: @Frank: Don't take it personal - we just want to keep things orderly. And FWIW, I think the tag can stay for now.

Comment: @code: Your thoughts on whether StackList should list non-API apps?

Comment: @geo - well, it is 'StackList' not 'StackApiList', so if you ask me, an app for the Stack that does not use the API might be the minority and probably should not require you to change the verbage on your site, probably would not be out of place and would welcome a long sought exposure vector.

Comment: Frank, you are presenting a real world example of a situation that has been in discussion for a while now. No worries. Until someone with a diamond next to their name says otherwise you are good.

Comment: @Frank: Okay. Feel free to list your app on [StackList](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/).

Comment: screen shot links seem gone and the main link 404s for me

Answer (score 2):

[Sesame Data Browser](http://metasapiens.com/sesame/data-browser/preview/) can also be used to browser OData and that includes Stack Exchange OData, of course.